# what happen if my node synced with uncle block?

Tags: nodes

I'm not sure that this question is correct or not.
But let me explain.

As you know, two blocks may be mined at almost same time then one of the block will be uncle block.

My question is what happen if uncle block is synchronized with my node.

For example, let's assume that my node got newly mined block numbered 10,600,000.

But, there was another mined block 10,600,000 at almost same time around the world and it is finally included as main blockchain.
So.. sadly, the block synced to my node become uncle block which can't belong to main Ethereum blockchain.

My question is.. in that case, when my node will synchronize with correct block 10,600,000?

Why I ask this is because I wonder whether every latest block synced to my node is always correct main block, or "sometimes" uncle block which will be resynced to my node.

If latter is correct, in order to guarantee data correctness, should I access 5times or 10times confirmed block instead of accessing the latest block?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to think the latest block or blocks that you’ve received could be orphaned. This is the reason you don’t immediately rely on data in the most recent blocks. You will generally want to wait for a certain number of confirmation blocks, to make sure the block you received will in fact be part of the longest chain moving forward and will not be orphaned.

A generally safe number of confirmations is 12. Exchanges tend to use far more. There are many other posts that can help you determine what the appropriate # of confirmations should be.